# How can I make a dynamic dropdown in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to make 'localitati' dropdown to show the elements depending on what element is selected in 'judete' dropdown.

I have tables 'judete' with idJudet and numeJudet columns and 'localitati' with idLocalitate idJudet and numeLocalitate columns in my database.

This is the code in view file:

```
Judetul:      <select name="judete" id="judete" required>
<option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
@foreach($judete as $jud)
<option value="{{$jud->idJudet}}">{{$jud->numeJudet}}</option>
@endforeach

</select>
<br><br>
Localitatea:  <select name="localitati" id="localitati" required>
</select>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#judete').change(function(){

var judete_id=$(this).val();
var div=$(this).parent();
var op=" ";

$.ajax({
type:'get',
url:'{!! URL::to('findLocalitati')!!}',
data:{'id':judete_id},
succes:function(data){

var op='<option value="0" selected disabled>Alege localitate</option>';
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
var op='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].localitati+'</option>';
}
div.find('.localitati').html(" ");
div.find('.localitati').append(op);
},
error:function(){
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

This is the code in providers:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Localitati extends Model
{
protected $table='localitati';
}
```

This is the code in routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('adauga');
});
Route::get('/', 'JudeteController@judetefunc');
Route::get('/findLocalitati', 'JudeteController@findLocalitati');
```

This is the code in Controllers:

```
class JudeteController extends Controller
{
public function judetefunc(){
$judete=Judete::all();
return view('judete', compact('judete'));
}
public function findLocalitati(Request $request){
$data=Localitati::select('numeLocalitate', 'idLocalitate')-
>where('idJudet', request->id)->take(100)->get();
return response()->json($data);
}
}
```

The 'localitati' dropdown is not showing anything.
Can you please tell me if I have some mistake in my code?
Thank you!

Comment: you need to post your code in the question, and remove the images. No one will help you with question like this...

Comment: You have not share the definition of your controller and in your routing page you have define 2 function over same route i.e / I mean home page.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @marius, can you copy and paste the code in the question, not the images...

Comment: I posted the code. Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: @marius, this is way better

Comment: You can check [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You should format the code as well, help people help you :)

Comment: `$('#judete).change(` should be `$('#judete').change(` (note the missing `'`)

Comment: also, `op+='<option value="0"...` change to var `var op ='<option value="0"...` (add `var` and remove `+`)

Comment: It is still not working. I tried to make the second drop-down independent from the first one. But this is not working either.